# Google reCaptcha validation (siteverify) returns false

Tags: php, recaptcha

I've tried to implement a simple code to use reCAPTCHA on my site afterwards, but even this simple code doesn't work.

The problem is that the verify function always returns a bool (false) value.
I've checked the keys several times but they are the correct ones

```
<head>
 <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
 <?php require_once "recaptchalib.php";  ?> 

    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['new_comment']) && !empty($_POST['new_comment'])):
            if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) :

                $secret = "mysecretkey";

                    var_dump ($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

                $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'].'&remoteip='.$ip);

                    echo ("verifyresponse");
                    var_dump ($verifyResponse);

                $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse, true);

                    echo ("responseData");
                    var_dump ($ResponseData);

                if ($response != null && $response->success) :

                    echo 'Form info successfully submitted';
                else:
                    $errMsg = 'Robot verification failed, please try again.';
                    echo $errMsg ;
                endif;
            else:
                $errMsg = 'Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.';
                echo $errMsg ;
            endif;
        else:
            $errMsg = '';
            $succMsg = '';
        endif;

        ?>

        <form name="form1" action="thisfile.php" method="post">
                    Enter Comment :<br />
                    <textarea name="new_comment" cols="75" rows="10"></textarea><br />
                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mysitekey"></div>

                    <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" />
        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

The `var_dump ($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])` gives the expected long chain of characters, but the `var_dump ($verifyResponse)` gives a `bool(false)` value, and I never see the `var_dump ($ResponseData)`.

Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong with this code?

I've narrowed down the problem to the fact that the `file_get_content` call returns a "false" value instead of the expected

> {
>         "success": true,
>          "challenge_ts": "2017-12-10T15:09:12Z",
>          "hostname": "mydomain"
>      }

What is getting me crazy is that if echo the full string and copy it directly in the browser then I get the correct answer (above), so I can't figure out what is going wrong...

Here's the current 'stripped to the bone' version of my code (I've deleted the `json_decode` call and everything after that since as long as I get a wrong return value I know the rest won't work)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer>
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

        define('GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_KEY','xxx');
        define('GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY','yyy');

        $message = false;

      if ( isset( $_POST['new_comment'], $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) && !empty( $_POST['new_comment'] ) && !empty( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) ){

      echo 'Sauvegarde du commentaire' ;
            $secret = GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY;
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                            var_dump($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

            $getResponse = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
                            var_dump($getResponse);

            $GoogleResponse = file_get_contents($getResponse) ;
                            var_dump($GoogleResponse) ;

      }

    ?>

    <form method='post'>
        Enter Comment :<br />
        <textarea name='new_comment' cols='75' rows='10'></textarea>
        <?php
            if( !empty( $message ) )echo $message;
        ?>
        <br />
        <div class='g-recaptcha' data-sitekey='<?php echo GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_KEY;?>'></div>
        <input type='submit' value='Envoyer' />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know it may sound dumb but presumably you are actually using a valid key rather than `$secret = "mysecretkey";`?

Comment: Thanks for the question. But indeed, I'm using the valid keys (both for secret and data-sitekey

Comment: can you share any changes you have made since posting the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Check you variables:

```
if ($responseData!= null && $responseData['success']) {
```

Additional edits for your code:

```
$secret = "Add Your Secret Key"; // may be you are adding here public key instead of private ? check it
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
$response = json_decode($response, true); // if you add "true" then the response will be an array

if($response["success"] === true){
    echo "Form Submit Successfully.";
}else{
    echo "You are a robot";
}
```

Also I advise you to look to these tutorial:

[Google Recaptcha Tutorial](http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/php-how-to-implement-google-new-recaptcha-code-example-with-demoexample.html)

And this recaptcha example from Github:

```
require('/path/to/recaptcha/src/autoload.php');
$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);
$resp = $recaptcha->verify($gRecaptchaResponse, $remoteIp);
if ($resp->isSuccess()) {
    // verified!
    // if Domain Name Validation turned off don't forget to check hostname field
    // if($resp->getHostName() === $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) {  }
} else {
    $errors = $resp->getErrorCodes();
}
```

[Github link](https://github.com/google/recaptcha)

Comment: Actually I can't. It seems the call to json_decode never returns. So anything I do after that doesn't show.

Comment: Have you added your domain to the google recaptcha admin ? @Frank

Comment: Thanks Cavid. I've added your code, but now it seems the problem is with http_build_query (apparently the execution of the code stops there). What do you mean "add my domain to the google recaptcha admin"? I've registered the site to get the keys; is there something else I should have done?

Comment: That's the problem: since the call to http_build_query does not return, I can't test for an error code. Execution just stops there, whatever I add in the code after that is just ignored.

Comment: Ok, i will give you another way

Comment: Just say which version of recaptcha do you use 1st or 2nd ?

Comment: That's reCAPTCHA version 2. Is there some library I should include to make the function call work?

Comment: I edited link to the first tutorial and also added another one which I use in my own project and works very well. Actually installing a recaptcha is not so  difficult. @Frank

Answer (score 0):

The reasons why this was failing were, I believe, as follows.

The first issue was the use of `true` as the 2nd parameter to `json_encode` - this puts the data in array format but you were trying to use Object syntax to access the `status` property of the returned json string.

```
$responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse, true);
```

so that should be

```
$responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
```

The 2nd issue  - two in one here. Where is `$response` defined? and the 2nd is as mentioned above - the use of Object syntax rather than array..

```
if ($response != null && $response->success)
```

should be (assuming `$responseData = json_decode( $verifyResponse );` )

```
if ( $verifyResponse != null && $responseData->success==1 )
```

The below was my test - more or less the same but older version of php so using curly braces instead of colon style..

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

            define('GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_KEY','xxxyyyzzz');
            define('GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY','aaabbbccc');

            $message = false;

            if ( isset( $_POST['new_comment'], $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) && !empty( $_POST['new_comment'] ) && !empty( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) ){

                $secret = GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY;
                $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                $response = file_get_contents( 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . $secret . '&response=' . $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] . '&remoteip=' . $ip );
                $json = json_decode( $response );

                /* 
                    You need to use $json->success not $response->success 
                    and because you are trying to use object syntax rather
                    than array syntax json_decode does not need 2nd param `true`
                */
                if( $response && !is_null( $response ) && $json->success==1 ){
                    $message='Form info successfully submitted';
                }else{
                    $message = 'Robot verification failed, please try again.';
                }
            }
        ?>

        <form method='post'>
            Enter Comment :<br />
            <textarea name='new_comment' cols='75' rows='10'></textarea>
            <?php
                if( !empty( $message ) )echo $message;
            ?>
            <br />
            <div class='g-recaptcha' data-sitekey='<?php echo GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_KEY;?>'></div>
            <input type='submit' value='Envoyer' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your code. I end up with the same problem: json_decode seems to never return after the call...